# java.io.IOException: Could not connect to BlobServer at address localhost/127.0.0.1:46385

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

**flink** version: **1.15.3** and **jdk** versioin: **1.8**
conf/flink-conf.yaml file here:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: test1
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager.bind-host: test1
taskmanager.bind-host: test1
taskmanager.host: test1
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
parallelism.default: 2
```

start a local cluster:

```
./bin/start-cluster.sh
```

Starting the SQL Client CLI by calling:

```
./bin/sql-client.sh embedded
```

then enter the simple query below and press Enter to execute it.

```
SET 'sql-client.execution.result-mode' = 'tableau';
SET 'execution.runtime-mode' = 'batch';

SELECT
  name,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  (VALUES ('Bob'), ('Alice'), ('Greg'), ('Bob')) AS NameTable(name)
GROUP BY name;
```

I got error:

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not upload job files.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobSubmitHandler.lambda$uploadJobGraphFiles$4(JobSubmitHandler.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.biApply(CompletableFuture.java:1105)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$BiApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1070)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1595)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not upload job files.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.ClientUtils.uploadJobGraphFiles(ClientUtils.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobSubmitHandler.lambda$uploadJobGraphFiles$4(JobSubmitHandler.java:195)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not connect to BlobServer at address localhost/127.0.0.1:35138
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobClient.<init>(BlobClient.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobSubmitHandler.lambda$null$3(JobSubmitHandler.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.ClientUtils.uploadJobGraphFiles(ClientUtils.java:82)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobClient.<init>(BlobClient.java:97)
    ... 14 more
]
```

why ?

Comment: Did you solve it ? Or can tell where can i change the host for Blob Serever